# Error magento menu in chrome - <li> HTML

Tags: html, css, magento

I am having the following problem, shown in pictures:

In Chrome:
[image: Google Chrome]

note that this cutting submenu, since Firefox is as follows:
[image: Firefox]

Do not understand what may be happening

a snippet of code

```
<li class="menu-item-link menu-item-depth-3 menuitemslinefirst menu-item-parent" style="background-color: transparent;">
    <a class="arrow" href="#">
        <span>&gt;</span>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <span>
            <img width="5" height="5" style="margin-top:8px; margin-left:10px" src="http://tecorp.com.br/skin/frontend/default/default/images/menu/icone/all.png" alt="">   Teclados
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="menu-container" style="display: block;">
        <li class="menu-item-text menu-item-depth-4  ">
        <ul class="em-catalog-navigation ">
            <li class="level0 nav-1 first">
                <a href="http://tecorp.com.br/index.php/teclados/teclados-com-fio.html">
                    <span>Teclados com Fio</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="level0 nav-2 last">
                <a href="http://tecorp.com.br/index.php/teclados/teclados-sem-fio.html">
                <span>Teclados sem Fio</span>
                </a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

an image of the css that is affecting this element if you need put the file

[image: css]

------------------------------------- EDIT ----------------------------------
Scouring the internet, by any chance can get where the error, if I take this part .show("slow"); and just put .show(); it work if I use "slow" it does not work in chrome

```
 $("# em_nav").show();
 $("# em_nav").show("slow");
```

Comment: Please include your CSS as well